# Creating a fraction graph in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Ok, so I was helping a friend of mine with a fraction problem on how to represent fractions so that they are easy to compare for children. We were thinking of a ruler and separate the ruler into pieces to represent the fractions and stack the rulers one on top of the other. And so we did, then I started to create something similar in `TikZ`.

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,3) rectangle (3,2);
\node at (0.5,2.5) {1};
\draw (-2,2) rectangle (3,1);
\draw (0.5,2)--(0.5,1);
\node at (-0.75,1.5) {$\frac{1}{2}$};
\node at (1.75,1.5) {$\frac{1}{2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

I was thinking on what would be the best way to do this drawing automatically by probably saying `\fracgraph{2}` or maybe `\fracgraph{5}{2}` where the first number controls the size of the diagram and the second controls the levels as to which the fractions go to; in this case it would be up to half.

This is what I have so far which is not much. I have only achieved the expansion of the graph (the rectangle containing it) up to the desired size but things like placing the nodes and splitting the diagram further, no.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}

\newcommand{\fracgraph}[2]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\meanfrac}{(0+#1)/2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (#1,\number\numexpr-#2\relax);
\node at (\meanfrac,-\number\numexpr #2/2\relax){#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\fracgraph{5}{2}
\end{document}
```

Any help into this abstract desire will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need `\number\numexpr` here, you can use directly #1 or #2. It's not like the problem with `\foreach`

Comment: I was just testing your last approach, am still learning some new ways. I had done it with #1 and #2 but I had to practice it so that it sticks in my head for a while.

Comment: I totally support your notion of using these kinds of visuals to help kids learn about fractions. I have 2 suggestions is that you make your fraction strips go to at least 3 wholes. In the short-run, that will slow things down. In the long-run, that will force them to compare/contrast fractional numbers with whole numbers, clarify mixed vs improper numbers, allow for more counting by fractions, etc. Also, the students are the ones who should be labeling your diagrams, not you! Feel free to use this. :)    https://bit.ly/31URTZz

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can produce it as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\fracgraph}[3][2]{%
    % #1 = optional height
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Yheight}{0.5*#1}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xincrement}{#2/#3}%

    \draw (0,0) rectangle (#2,#1);
    \node at ($(0.5*#2,0.75*#1)$) {1};
    \draw ($(0,\Yheight)$) -- ($(#2,\Yheight)$);
    \foreach \x in {2,...,#3} {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xcoord}{(\x-1)*\Xincrement}%
        \draw ($(\Xcoord,0)$) -- ($(\Xcoord,)$);
    }%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#3} {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\XcoordLabel}{(\x-0.5)*\Xincrement}%
        \node at ($(\XcoordLabel,0.5*\Yheight)$) {$\frac{1}{#3}$};
    }%
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\fracgraph{5}{2}

\bigskip
\fracgraph{5}{3}

\bigskip
\fracgraph{5}{4}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to have just one diagram then I would suggest changing the syntax to something like:

```
\fracgraph{5}{2/cyan!50,3/red!40,4/brown!50}
```

where the text following the slash indicates the fill color to be applied to yield:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{CountOfSections}
\newcommand{\fracgraph}[3][1]{%
    % #1 = optional height
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (#2,#1) node [midway] {1};

    \setcounter{CountOfSections}{0}%
    \foreach \Size/\Options in {#3} {%
        \stepcounter{CountOfSections}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\YCoord}{#1*\arabic{CountOfSections}}%
        \draw  (0,-\YCoord) rectangle (#2,-\YCoord+#1);
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xincrement}{#2/\Size}%
         \foreach \x in {1,...,\Size} {%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xcoord}{\x*\Xincrement}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\XcoordLabel}{(\x-0.5)*\Xincrement}%
            \draw [fill=\Options]  ($(\Xcoord-\Xincrement,-\YCoord)$)  rectangle ($(\Xcoord,-\YCoord+#1)$);
            \node at ($(\XcoordLabel,-\YCoord+0.5*#1)$) {$\frac{1}{\Size}$};
        }%
    }%
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
    \fracgraph{5}{2/cyan!50,3/red!40,4/brown!50}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can the split of the rectangle remain to indicate for `\fracgraph{5}{4}` let say showing 1 then half below, a third below half and so on? In your example, you only show one then half or a third and so on and not the intermediate splittings.

Comment: @azetina: Ok, have updated solution.

Comment: How can I modify the code if i want I do to draw separate rectangles? I mean, I would like to draw the four rectangles (white 1, blue 1/2, pink 1/3 and brown 1/4) separated by each other. Thank you @PeterGrill

Comment: @ryuk: Adjusting the `\Xincrement` in each iteration should do it. If you run into difficulties, best to post a new question showing how you attempted to adpat the code above.